# \topsep in nested list ignored

Tags: lists, enumitem, vertical-spacing, nesting

I don't know if this is a LaTeX problem or an `enumitem` problem, but it seems that `\topsep` (and similarly `\partopsep`) is ignored in nested lists if the list starts in vertical mode.

Consider the following example with `topsep=10pt` to exaggerate.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item a % list starts after text
        \begin{enumerate}[topsep=10pt]
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
        b
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item % list starts without text
        \begin{enumerate}[topsep=10pt]
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
        b
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As seen in the first list, `topsep` of `10pt` is added above and below the list, as expected. Here the list is preceded by some text.

In the second list, `topsep` is completely ignored, printing *b* immediately after the end of the list. Here the list starts directly after `\item` without text. I'd expect that a vertical space of `topsep` would be placed after the list at least. The same happens if one replaces `a` by `\leavevmode`.

This becomes especially problematic if one starts a theorem-like environment with a list, and after that one types text. Depending on the style of the list, this could become indistinguishable from normal paragraphs.

So why is that the case? And how could one fix this? The fix probably uses the `after` key, but should detect this specific case (i.e. that the list starts without text if nested) somehow.

Answer (score 0):

To help out perhaps:

- Without `\topsep` but with `before` and `after={\leavevmode\vspace{10pt}}`

Remark: test with and without `\leavevmode` in the code `before`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{%
  % before={\vspace{10pt}},
  before={\leavevmode\vspace{10pt}},
  after={\leavevmode\vspace{10pt}}
  }

\begin{enumerate}
    \item a % list starts after text
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
        b
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item % list starts without text
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
        b
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not quite perfect. If I use the option without `\leavevmode`, then in the second list, the `\vspace{10pt}` in `before` is added in between the two *parent list*, which is not what I wanted (hence why I wrote "should detect this specific case"). Something like the `\addvspace` mechanism could help. Moreover, you should set `topsep=0pt` to really replace `\topsep`.